# i need to read from a text file save to an array and then generate a report

Tags: java, arrays

Create a loop that works till the array of passengers is empty. Inside this loop you have to:
Generate a random number from 1 to 6.Add to the Queue, which you have in your Airport class, a number of passengers equal to the number that you just generated. You need to take these passengers from the array.
I cant get it to add elements from the array to the queue . Here is what i have tried

```
  void runningStimulation() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String Line = "";

    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("passengers.dat")));
    List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {

        Line = inFile1.nextLine();
        temps.add(Line);

    }
    inFile1.close();
    String[] passengers = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (String s : passengers) {
        System.out.println(s);

        int Random = new Random().nextInt(6);
        int k = Random;
        addqueue(passengers(k));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
int k = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
```

because Random().nextInt(n) gives you a random in [0,n[.

after your comment i would suggest this to replace your for:

```
int rng = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
for(int i = 0; i < rng; i++){
    Passenger p = new Passenger(passenger[i] /* TODO: default_constructor, assuming that the argument for Passenger constructor is String */);
    addqueue(p);
}
```

Comment: but how do i add this number of passengers to the queue ? this generated number must be the number of passengers taken from the array to the queue

Comment: @lele i rewrote the answer to answer better your comment.

Comment: it gives an error with addqueue(passengers[i]); it says string cannot be converted to passenger

Comment: @lele you dont show much of your code. Maybe your queue is of passengers? Queue<Passenger>? I assumed you were using addqueue(String s) from your original code.

Comment: Passenger[] Passengers= new Passenger[MaxStay]; this is my queue

Comment: @lele updated based on your comment. And Passenger[] is not a queue, is an array.